# Java Tesseract dyld: Symbol not found:

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

im trying to do simple OCR application but i get errors like this:

Code:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

    public class Main { 
        public void tesseract(String filename){
            BytePointer outText;

            tesseract.TessBaseAPI api = new tesseract.TessBaseAPI();
            // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
            if (api.Init("/Users/Marcel/tesseract-ocr", "ENG") != 0) {
                System.err.println("Could not initialize tesseract.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            // Open input image with leptonica library
            PIX image = pixRead(filename);
            api.SetImage(image);
            // Get OCR result
            outText = api.GetUTF8Text();
            String string = outText.getString();
            assertTrue(!string.isEmpty());
            System.out.println("OCR output:\n" + string);

            // Destroy used object and release memory
            api.End();
            outText.deallocate();
            pixDestroy(image);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Main main = new Main();
            String fileName = "src/main/resources/test.png";

            main.tesseract(fileName);
      }
    }
```

I have tried some solutions from google, but it didnt solve this. I using Inteliji (with maven) on Mac OSX. Before i had problem with TESTDATA_PREFIX, but i changed api.init first parameter and now i get this:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI8SetImageEPK3Pix
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/lq/3mb8s_jj1ql0klqzznm1j1tm0000gn/T/javacpp33697284992581/libjnitesseract.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN9tesseract11TessBaseAPI8SetImageEPK3Pix
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/lq/3mb8s_jj1ql0klqzznm1j1tm0000gn/T/javacpp33697284992581/libjnitesseract.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of 2 conflicting `libtesseract.3.dylib`.
If you have installed `tesseract` on mac using brew then it is referring to the `libtesseract.3.dylib` inside `tesseract` folder `/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.01_1/lib/`
instead of `/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib`